# trying to find even numbers but program just doesnt seem to work

Tags: c

I've written a program that will determine if your input is even or not, it doesn't seem to be working though. What seems to be the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x, y;
  x = 0;
  while (x < 5) {
    printf("input a number\n");
    scanf("%d", y);
    if (y % 2 == 0) printf("your number is an even number\n");
    else print("your number is not an even number\n");
    x++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: im sorry i wrote (y%2==0) first but that doesnt help either it still isnt working

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` needs a pointer to the output variable:

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

It's not a C++ function so it can't accept variables by reference.

Comment: +1 Mention checking return value of `scanf()` to ensure `y` has been assigned.